# SQL problem, LEFT JOIN [..] IN()

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-error-1054

This small SQL error is bugging me. It doesn't seem to be a problem with the query, just the scope(?), examples work best:

```
SELECT ocp.*, oc.*, GROUP_CONCAT( u.username SEPARATOR ', ') AS `memjoined`
FROM gangs_ocs_process ocp, gangs_ocs oc
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.userid IN ( ocp.membersin )
WHERE ocp.ocid =1 AND ocp.gangid =1 AND oc.oc_name = ocp.crimename
GROUP BY ocp.ocid
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Theres a column (gangs_ocs_process.membersin) which has a list of IDs that have joined (ie 1,2,5). I'm trying to get the usernames for each of these IDs (from the `users` table) in one go.

The problem is `LEFT JOIN users u ON u.userid IN ( ocp.membersin )`

If I substitue `1,2,4` in for `ocp.membersin` (putting the literal list instead of column name), it works ok. It returns a column that has the usernames ([image](http://decepti0n.com/u/f/tmp_fTceB.jpg)). However, if I leave in the ocp.membersin, I get this error:

`#1054 - Unknown column 'ocp.membersin' in 'on clause'`

This is the first time I've even used IN in left joins so I'm a bit lost.

Any help would be great :)

Comment: sorry for the 1 million edits. Can you elaborate the relation between gangs_ocs_process, gangs_oc, and users.

Comment: It's ok. The relation doesn't matter much since it returns the column as a string, which won't work properly with the IN which needs just a list of values. Most of the edits you made did work, but we both seemed to miss this point until Jeremy there pointed it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that "IN" will work for this syntax.  MySQL expects IN to be something akin to a dataset, not a delimited string.  I think you need to find a way to take membersin, expand it into a dataset MySQL can work with (maybe a temporary table), and join on that.

Comment: Yes - I'm pretty sure that's it now. The column has 1,2,3, but turns it into `userid IN ('1,2,3')`, which only fetches one. I'll have to expand/use two queries

Answer (score 2):

If you have delimited strings in your table, you have a design problem in your database.  Add a new table to hold these values.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't get it to work is because first you need to get your database NORMALIZED. You should NEVER, EVER have a list of ID's in a single column.

Comment: I'm using (trying) IN because the membersin col has multiple values, and I'm getting multiple rows back from the users table (grouping them with GROUP_CONCAT()). I tried your method as well, but it still says unknown column.

Comment: Ok, then your problem is simple - your database is DENORMALIZED and that is the source of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **bad way** to keep membership.

But if you still need to live with it, you may try `REGEXP` matching to test for membership:

```
SELECT ocp.*, oc.*, GROUP_CONCAT( u.username SEPARATOR ', ') AS `memjoined`
FROM gangs_ocs_process ocp
LEFT JOIN users u ON (ocp.membersin RLIKE CONCAT('(^|,)[[:blank:]]?', userid, '[[:blank:]]?($|,)'))
JOIN gangs_ocs oc ON (ocp.ocid = 1 AND ocp.gangid = 1 AND oc.oc_name = ocp.crimename)
GROUP BY ocp.ocid
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: It seems to partly work, I moved it back to two joins like you posted. The error doesn't come up, however, even though the `membersin` column is '1,2,3', it only returns one `users` row (I used the same IN() syntax as above)

Answer (score 0):

After taking another look, I think your problem is trying to aggregate at the wrong point as well as the IN syntax and that you should aggregate in a subquery restricted by the contents of the IN. I don't know enough about your schema to make this out of the box correct, but you want something like this. SomeKeyfield should relate back to gangs_ocs_process

```
SELECT ocp.*, oc.*, u.Memjoined
FROM gangs_ocs_process ocp, gangs_ocs oc
LEFT JOIN (Select SomeKeyField, GROUP_CONCAT( u.username SEPARATOR ', ') as memjoined
            from  users where userid in
            (select membersin from gangs_ocs_process 
             where [whatever conditions] )
             Group By SomeKeyField) u on ocp.SomeKeyField = u.SomeKeyField

WHERE ocp.ocid =1 AND ocp.gangid =1 AND oc.oc_name = ocp.crimename
GROUP BY ocp.ocid
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure 'membersin' is in the 'gangs_ocs_process' table, and not the 'gangs_ocs' table?

Comment: Made me double check heh, but yes it is.